# How do I set the Julia init path on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, julia

I have the Julia application on my Mac as follows:

```
$ alias julia
alias julia='exec '\''/Applications/Julia-0.4.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia'\'''
```

I'd like to be able to call Julia from Python (or a Jupyter/IPython notebook):

```
from julia import Julia
```

However, in the next step, none of the following methods work:

```
jl = Julia()
jl = Julia(jl_init_path="/Applications/Julia-0.4.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin")
jl = Julia(jl_init_path="/Applications/Julia-0.4.5.app/Contents/Resources/")
```

In the latter case, I'm getting the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Applications/Julia-0.4.5.app/Contents/Resources/usr/bin/julia'
```

So obviously it's trying to find a path to Julia that starts with `usr/bin/julia`.  However, there is no `usr/` folder in `/Applications/Julia-0.4.5.app`.  What's the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 7):

I set up a symbolic link from my `/usr/local/bin` directory (note: you'll probably need to use sudo to do this):

```
ln -s /Applications/Julia-0.4.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia
```

I use `/usr/local/bin`, you may need to change that to `/usr/bin`, if your version of Mac OS X allows that.